# Gem 'merit' not counting points

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

The goal is to give a user points when his comment gets an upvote. Now it just gives points when the comment is created(5 points) and doesn't count upvotes.

I've looked at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20649153/2744900) and according to it my code is correct. I'm using [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) gem for upvotes/downvotes.

gemfile

```
gem 'merit', '~> 2.1.1'
```

comments_controller

```
  def upvote
   @comment.liked_by current_user
   render "update_likes"
  end
```

point_rules

```
module Merit
  class PointRules
    include Merit::PointRulesMethods

    def initialize

      score 5, :on => ['comments#create'], :to => [:user], category: 'gold_points'
      score 2, :on => ['comments#upvote'], :to => [:user], category: 'gold_points' 

    end
  end
end
```

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_merit
```

display points

```
<%= @user.points(category: 'gold_points') %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

change

```
render "update_likes"
```

to

```
render :nothing => true
```